# Setting mock location remotely

Tags: adb, gps, geolocation

For testing purposes, I need to fake my GPS location on a real Android device. Now, I know about the possibility of Android Emulator and setting their GPS location via telnet.

I don't really have a clue how those GPS Faker Apps set the mock location of an Android device and that isn't really the question, but I wondered if there is a way to set the mock location of a *real* Android device other than using these apps. And additionally, I need to do this over an interface so I can do this from my computer.

Is it possible to set up a telnet server on an Android device? Or maybe I should write a minimalistic app that I can run via ADB? And how do I know the GPS module of my device doesn't overwrite my set mock location?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an app for this. If you're into building yourself, here are the sources: https://github.com/juliusmh/RemoteGeoFix